# Is there a term which covers ATM cards, credit cards, and debit cards?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests, hypernyms

I work in accommodation for international travelers, and people can pay with various kinds of cards:

- In some countries such as USA, [credit cards](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Credit_card) are very common, but debit cards are not so common.
- In other regions such as Europe, most people have [debit cards](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Debit_card), but credit cards are quite a bit less common.
- These days in Australia both kinds of cards are very common.

Often customers are confused when I ask if they want to pay (or make a reservation) with credit card because they know they have a debit card and not a credit card. And there are other kinds of cards like [ATM cards](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ATM_card) and [EFTPOS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EFTPOS) cards. These can be used for payment but not for making reservations because they cannot be charged without access to the physical cards.

**I've taken to using the circumlocution "Mastercard or Visa card", but I wonder if there's a better term?** For instance Maestro cards are related to Mastercards and usually work here too.

All the cards have the same form factor and either/both a magnetic strip and/or smartcard chip. They are all processed with the same machine.

A few weeks ago I stumbled across the term ["payment card" on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Payment_card), that I couldn't recall hearing before. I thought this would be the right term, but it seems not to include ATM cards so I guess I should rule it out ...

(My second reason for looking for this term is to decide on which tag or tags to use for such cards over on [travel.SE](http://travel.stackexchange.com), where we currently only have a [`credit-cards` tag](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/credit-cards), but more and more questions about the other kinds of cards too.)

Comment: (The best term should be understood by the majority of people from most English-speaking countries, at least including Australia, Canada, Ireland, New Zealand, the United Kingdom, and USA.)

Comment: Does 'bank card' work?

Comment: @Mitch: Possibly. I'm not sure how widely it's used. Some cards are from building societies or credit unions though.

Comment: [Charge card](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Charge_card)?

Comment: @TerryLi: I think *charge cards* are another kind of card. We don't have them in Australia - I think of them as an American thing.

Comment: I wouldn't say credit cards are less common in Europe - everyone basically has either separate credit and debit cards, or increasingly a VISA or similar card that can do both.

Comment: @AlanB: Yes I couldn't remember which people seemed to never have them. Maybe it was English, maybe Germans, I only recalled that most of our guests are Europeans but only the North Americans and Aussies seem to ever choose the credit option on the card machine.

Comment: Can you not just ask them *How would you like to pay?*

Comment: @CarlSmith: Well sometimes they are paying and sometimes they are making a booking over the telephone in which case they only leave their card details but don't pay at that time.

Comment: Another option could be to just say that you take credit cards.  Although debit card and credit cards are two separate forms of card payment, I think the system was designed so that a debit card can always be used where a credit card is accepted.  However, the opposit is not true.  Some stores opt to only accept debit cards because the bank pays the fees for those transactions, rather than the merchant.  This is often the case when the merchant receives a high volume of low-dollar transactions.

Comment: @RLH: It turns out that true credit cards are rare in Europe and many Europeans take it literally to mean their other kind of card won't work! Also many places don't accept American Express and Diners Club due to the high fees they charge merchants. Even "debit card" has subtly different meanings between places. In Australia it's used for a Visa or Mastercard that only access your bank account and not credit. In Europe or the UK it seems to mean a card issued by a bank without credit whether or not it's Visa or Mastercard. Presumably they work with domestic POS networks. It's all messy (-:

Answer (score 67, accepted):

The industry itself uses the term **Payment Card**. See [this Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Payment_card_industry) for details. In IT you frequently hear the term "PCI compliant" to refer to software that meets security standards set out by the *Payment Card Industry Security Standards Council,* a consortium of players in the payment card business.

In practice the term isn't used often, but if you're looking for a single term I don't think there's a better one out there. I think the reason most merchants spell out which types of payment cards they take - "Visa, Mastercard, ATM and gift cards" for example - is because there's a lot of choices out there and most places do not accept all of them.

Comment: Thanks @Marcus. I guess you didn't notice the last paragraph in my question where I mention this term and Wikipedia article. Reading it though gave me the impression that it didn't include ATM cards.

Comment: @hippietrail The article I linked references PCI; the PCI standards certainly do cover ATM cards. I do agree that the article in your link doesn't cover ATMs specifically.

Comment: Aha well if the Wikipedia article is faulty then this is indeed the best term thanks!

Comment: I'm accepting this because even though it won't be familiar to many people, being a somehow official term makes it a good umbrella term in many arenas anyway, if not perhaps best for the primary use case I explained. Also, it's totally clear even if you haven't heard it before or have poor English.

Comment: It's slightly unfortunate that "PCI card" (even if it's a redundant abbreviation) usually means [something else](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conventional_PCI).

Answer (score 36):

Some places have used the term plastic. It makes it clear it is not cash, or a check. It could be a credit card, debit card, or even a gift card.

Comment: Yes colloquial/informal but it certainly works.

Comment: Will that be cash, check, or plastic?

Comment: In fact once I swipe the plastic the machine usually asks: cheque, savings, or credit?

Comment: @GEdgar: I wish the teller had said that when I went to pay my local property tax. Instead, she said "paper or plastic?" and confused me for a solid 90 seconds while I tried to figure out *what could they possibly be bagging for me?*

Comment: Actually, as RobAu mentioned [in a comment on another answer](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/101920/is-there-a-term-which-covers-atm-cards-credit-cards-and-debit-cards/102006#comment207277_101925), this will confuse some people who are newly arrived in countries with [plastic (polymer) banknotes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polymer_banknote), such as Australia and New Zealand.

Answer (score 18):

All of these things can be called *bank cards* as banks typically issue ATM cards, credit cards, and debit cards.

Comment: In which regions is this term used? I know of cards issued by at least credit unions and building societies too. And I think in some countries even some large department stores issue their own cards.

Comment: The term is understood in the UK. I've no idea where Hugo is.

Comment: @hippietrail http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/bank_card , http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bank_card | There's also _cash card_ which in some places is synonymous only with ATM cards. Is there some reason why you don't want to just use the word, _card_? The standard question is "Do you want to pay by cash or card?", right?

Comment: I had a feeling I'd heard it from British people. I seem to recall hearing *cash card* too. Here in Australia that was a brand name of one of the first ATM cards about thirty years ago.

Comment: In Canada, anyway, a "bank card" would be synonymous with a debit card that a bank issues. Nobody would understand that to mean "credit card".

Comment: One reason to avoid the word *card* is that we also use plastic cards for the guests' room keys and for Wi-Fi access codes. Of course ambiguities can usually be avoided but for people with poor English it's good to have clear terms, especially when talking to somebody over an expensive but poor quality telephone connection where you want to talk fast and avoid repeating and clarifying as much as possible.

Answer (score 15):

Here (UK) it would be common to just use *card*, e.g. "Can I pay by card?".

Comment: It doesn't work so well with "I'll need your card number to hold your reservation". Some people would understand, some wouldn't.

Comment: I'd consider that normal idiomatic usage but quite possibly is not universal.

Comment: Well in the UK people tend to just say credit card to mean both and assume that everywhere that takes a credit card also accepts debit

Comment: @hippietrail especially if they think you mean a "loyalty card"!

Comment: Then when they say yes, hand them a 6 of clubs.

Answer (score 14):

I have often heard debit cards, credit cards, ATM cards etc., referred to as *'**plastic money**'*. I am not sure if that term is used in the UK, USA, Canada, Australia and New Zealand, but here is some [source](http://money.blurtit.com/q216104.html) if you need to know more about the term.

Comment: It's informal/colloquial but a good answer thanks.

Comment: Funny, in New Zealand the paper money is in fact very plastic-like

Comment: @RobAu not sure if you're joking :) but New Zealand bank notes are actually made of plastic http://www.rbnz.govt.nz/currency/money/0094127.html

Comment: Yes, I remembered correctly then :)

Comment: Which is weird since most money is not made of paper anymore, but plastic as well :)

Comment: I have heard and used the terms "check", "cash", and "plastic" to identify the three ways I most frequently pay for things. Checks may be cashier's, checking, or line of credit. Cash may be either US or other currency. And plastic may be credit, debit, pre-paid, or gift.

Answer (score 4):

I have had the same issue and have done one of the following:

1. Said "credit or debit card". Clear, and not terribly long.
2. Stated the type of cards accepted ("Visa or Mastercard", or "Laser, Visa or Mastercard"). This has the bonus of immediately dealing with someone having a card of a type that isn't taken.

> Maestro cards are related to Mastercards and usually work here too.

That *usually* can catch people out though, as it has me when travelling with one of the exceptions - a maestro debit card not accepted where Mastercard is, and hence not working for my purchase. I would much rather they hadn't claimed to accept Maestro when actually they accepted Mastercard and by extension those Maestro which are accepted when Mastercard are.

Comment: When we do have problems, it's mostly with Maestro cards. We don't have Maestro in Australia. Our new card machine seems to be better with them though. Usually I can get them to work by manually entering the number if they refuse to work by swiping.

Comment: @hippietrail there's both technical and organisational differences betwee different Maestro cards. A new machine might help the former, but not the latter.

Answer (score 4):

As a Commercial Banker for over 10 years, a current Insurance and Financial Services company owner, and utilizing my M.B.A. in Finance, the term I have seen universally used and use myself is **"Finance Card."**

Answer (score 3):

**Electronic Cash Cards** seems good.

Wiki : [Electronic cash](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electronic_cash) states about *Electronic cash with a magnetic stripe card*.

Comment: +1. Very apt term and something I first heard about 10-15 years back when they were coming and about and were not that common. Common technical term to refer to such kind of money. I believe even just *Electronic Cash* or *Electronic Money* will do, no need to add "card" after that.

Comment: *Cards* is superfluous I think. *Electronic cash* or even *eCash* should be good enough.

Comment: Well credit cards didn't use to be electronic. Merchants had devices which took an impression of the embossed details on carbon paper. ([image](http://www.phonebooth.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2012/12/credit-card-machine.jpg) ... can't seem to find a picture of one on Wikipedia.) These might still be in use somewhere. Also there are other kinds of electronic money such as PayPal and Bitcoin.

Comment: 'Electronic cash is the debit card system of the German Banking Industry Committee, the association which represents the top German financial interest groups. An electronic card payment is generally made by the card owner entering their PIN (Personal Identification Number) at a so-called EFT-POS-terminal (Electronic-Funds-Transfer-Terminal). Comparable debit card systems are Maestro and Visa Electron. Banks and credit institutions who issue these cards often pair EC debit cards with Maestro functionality.' (Adapted from _Wikipedia_)

Answer (score 2):

They're generally called as '**Plastic cards**' or just '**Plastic**'. You must have heard the term often - Plastic Money'

Comment: Yes in fact it's already been mentioned twice before you `(-;` ([1](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/101923/3175), [2](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/101925/3175)) It's common enough in some places. The drawbacks are that it's informal/colloquial; in my use case it could be confused with our plastic key cards and our plastic Internet cards; and that more and more countries, including mine, have polymer banknotes - another kind of plastic money.

Answer (score 1):

In the UK it's often colloquially referred to as just *plastic* — so one might ask a small retailer if they accept debit/credit cards by saying "Do you take plastic?"