# Card machine vs Card terminal

Tags: vocabulary

When you go to a restaurant and you want to pay by card, in american English, what do ask the waiter for? for them to please bring the card machine? or card terminal? or any other term?

Comment: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/133279/what-do-we-call-the-machine-used-in-shops-through-which-we-swipe-our-debit-credi

Comment: neither, you usually ask for check or bill

Comment: The terminology for a table-side credit card reader is not established.  Just ask for your check and let the server suggest options.

Comment: thanks but i meant the machine itself